What are my options for stripping this paint?
Our front walk and porch are concrete that has been painted a few times over. 
I'd like to get all of the paint up. My strategy to date has taken two forms:

Watch for bubbles and use a putty knife to take up the bubbled paint and any surrounding loose chips.
Coat small areas with orange oil paint stripper. This doesn't seem to get through all the paint layers.
Dawn and sand -- didn't work.

I would like to figure out a more effective way to get the paint up.
Someone mentioned sand blasting it, but I don't even know how I would go about that.
I'm open to strategies that take some time to work or will just be a smidge faster than peeling at the edges of chipped areas.

Ask at your local rental store.  They should have a tool or different types of tools to do the job.  Might be a sand blaster, large grinder, maybe even a pressure washer.

Duh, you wrote "walk" but I saw "wall." New glasses on order. I wrote an answer for "wall" but I'm leaving it as-is because it doesn't change anything.
If you sandblast a concrete wall by renting a towable gasoline or diesel powered compressor and a sandblasting rig, it will certainly take the paint off the wall. However, it will also take particles of sand off the surface of the concrete and expose the aggregate, leaving an uneven and unsightly surface.
If you follow the same process, but instead of sand you use ground up walnut shells, coconut shells, corncobs or other organic abrasives, that will take off the paint but it will leave the concrete mostly intact. But consider the expense.
I've removed multiple layers of decades-old paint from concrete block exterior garage walls by mixing up my own caustic paint remover. I mixed about a cup of lye pellets into a quart of water and stirred while adding 1-2 tablespoons of cornstarch to make the solution thick. The reaction between the water and lye makes the solution boiling hot, which prompts the cornstarch to thicken. I applied it to the wall with a paint brush.
Without the cornstarch, the solution doesn't work well because it runs off the wall before it has time to work. With cornstarch, the solution is thick and a layer of it stays on the wall until you rinse it off. The paint bubbles and loses its adhesion to the wall.
After letting the solution sit on the paint for 15 minutes or so, I would wash it off with a garden hose from a safe distance, then hit the wall with a power washer to get the last bits of paint off. Occasional small spots required a second treatment, but for the most part I was left with completely clean, paint-free masonry.
WARNING WARNING WARNING
Caustic paint remover is dangerous. It used to be what everyone used to remove paint, and so many people were injured or blinded by it that industry came up with what they now advertise as "safe" paint remover. I haven't seen caustic paint remover available for purchase in decades.
Don't even think about trying this unless you can work in an area free of children, animals and pedestrians. You'll have to don full-body protective clothing, including splashproof goggles, a face shield, rubber gauntlets and rubber boots. If you get lye solution in your eyes, it can blind you. On your skin it will burn you and leave a scar. Fumes emitted when you mix the solution can choke you. If you're not confident in your ability to work with dangerous chemicals, just don't try it.
But hey, it's cheap and it works better for paint on concrete than anything I know.

Great info, but I would be inclined to  paint the concrete an acceptable color rather than risk life or sight to remove the old paint.

@RMDman That's certainly the safest choice, no argument. But it's peeling and chipping, which is why the OP wants the old paint off. If I had more common sense than bravado and didn't want to spend what it would cost for walnut shell blasting, I guess I would scrape what's loose, sand the scraped areas smooth, and paint over it. It wouldn't look perfect, but it would be an improvement.

Yeah, I have encountered a lot of painted concrete in my experiences flipping and  doing reno on homes.  I hate painted concrete, but always found repainting in a color that accents the home was the best,   ( easiest) option for me.

@RMDman painting it is definitely the easy option, but it will just chip and peel again. My neighbors redo their walkway every year or two. I'm sure they love that I've just let mine chip slowly away.

@Amanda,  It's your concrete. You can do as you wish. I'm just saying the work and expense needed to strip the paint is something I would not do.  Heck you can break up all the concrete and re-pour new.  I'm just stating my opinion.
